# 1:1 OData ReferentialConstraint with wrong keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have two entities `Customer` and `Address` that is a 1-to-1 relationship. Customer has `ID, AddressId, Name` and Address has `ID and AddressName`. Whenever I call `entityType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(propertyOnEntity, propertyOnTargetEntity);` the metadata associations come out with:

```
<Association Name="K2SmartObjects_Customer_Address_K2SmartObjects_Address_Customer">
<End Type="K2SmartObjects.Address" Role="Address" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
<End Type="K2SmartObjects.Customer" Role="Customer" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
<ReferentialConstraint>
<Principal Role="Customer">
<PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
</Principal>
<Dependent Role="Address">
<PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
</Dependent>
</ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Shouldn't the principal role have `AddressId` as the `PropertyRef`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `ID` be the foreign key in the dependent `Address` type? You don't reference a `Customer` via `AddressId`. Therefore, I see no problem in `ID` being the principal property. For your reference, see [here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-02-referential-constraint) and [here](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#17-36-define-referential-constraints).